# How to disable mat-tab-group mat-ink-bar animation

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-tab

I wan to disable a selection animation

I set `animationDuration` and `disableRipple` but it still animated

```
<mat-tab-group animationDuration="0ms" disableRipple>
        <mat-tab label="Short tab">
          <div class="mat-elevation-z4_">
            Small content
          </div>
        </mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label="Long tab">
          <div class="mat-elevation-z4_">
            Large content
          </div>
        </mat-tab>
      </mat-tab-group>
```

[image]

I want it to work same as in the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/examples)

[image]

UPDATE:

I've ried `[@.disable]="true"` but it didn't work

```
<mat-tab-group animationDuration="0ms" [@.disabled]="true">
        <mat-tab label="Short tab">
          <div class="mat-elevation-z4_">
            Small content
          </div>
        </mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label="Long tab">
          <div class="mat-elevation-z4_">
            Large content
          </div>
        </mat-tab>
 </mat-tab-group>
```

UPDATE:

the only way I fixed that transition is by placing this custom css `::ng-deep .mat-ink-bar{ transition: none !important; }`

Answer (score 2):

`animationDuration="0"` can remove [animation](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#controlling-the-tab-animation) for tabs, but not for the ink bar

for ink bar you can delete animation with the [provider](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/tabs/ink-bar.ts) in your component

`providers: [ { provide: ANIMATION_MODULE_TYPE, useValue: 'NoopAnimations' } ]`

Answer (score 0):

Viktoria's solution is nice, but beware that it will disable ALL animations in your component. I.e. if you have a loading wheel, it won't turn anymore.